# How to access this.props in the react navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react navigation in my React Native app, I want to call the function onSavePress() when I a user clicks Save button on the top right of the App.

But when I try to call the onSavePress function my app crashes, in otherwords it doesnt like I call that function from inside the static navigationOptions function.

Here's the code below:

```
class TheFormScreen extends Component {

  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        visible: true
      };
  }

  state = {
      isReady: false,
    };


static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: `${navigation.state.params.item.a1}`,
    tabBarIcon:  ({ tintColor }) => {
          return <Icon name="phone" size={30} color={tintColor} />;
    },
    headerRight: (
      <Btn
        title='Done-'
        onPress={() => { console.log(' on Press done on line 73 Form--Screen    this.props=', this.props);  navigation.goBack()   }
         }
      />
    ),
  });

onDecline(){
  // console.log(' onDecline  clicked');
  this.setState ({ showModal : false });
}



}
onDeleteProperty() {
  // console.log(' onDelete  clicked');

}


onSavePress(){
    this.onClickToaster();
    console.log( '101 - on click onSavePress ');
    const { a1, a2 } = this.props;

    this.props.propertySave({  a1, a2 });
}
```

Comment: you can't do that in the static block. Read up about the static keyword so you understand it. Also, to answer your question, take a look at https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/145

Answer (score 0):

So, this is just a clear snippet of all the code ad infoSave is no where and onSavePress too.

I am assuming your problem is that this.props is undefined or something like that. If that is the case, you can bind this changing the function into an arrow function:

```
onSavePress = () => {
    this.onClickToaster('Saving the info....', 'top' , DURATION.LENGTH_LONG, true);
    const { a1, a2 } = this.props;
    this.props.infoSave({  a1, a2 });
}
```

Edit:

You mean this?

```
 headerRight: (
  <Btn
    title='Save'
    onPress={() => { this.onSavePress();  navigation.goBack()   }
     }
  />
),
```

Comment: Hence the question how to call the function onSavePress, from the top right of the react-navigation ?

Comment: See my edit. Although it is very confusing since you are obviously assuming a lot of code that is not in the question. Is all of these code in the same class? Same file? Why is not working? It will be easier to help if you can add more info

Comment: Yes all of this is in the same class.